# Can rhel-7-server-extras-rpm repo be added to yum without using subscription-manager?

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel, rhel7

On RHEL7, is there a way to run

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpm
```

without using the subscription-manager?

(i.e., without executing a command like `subscription-manager register --username=<RH UserName> --auto-attach`)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the repo file manually. However `subscription-manager` download certificate, which is used to authenticate and authorize to Red Hat Portal so without that certificate it will be useless anyway.